# Can someone force-freeze this formula using INDIRECT()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

INDIRECT() seemed easy for tiny formulas but it didnt seem that easy for the below formula. The reason I want to freeze is whenever I delete the rows in FormResponses, the formula in the second tab is going haywire.

So watevr happens in FormResponses, I want the formula to be rock steady.

```
 =SUM(ArrayFormula(('Form Responses 1'!$B$2:$B=A2)*('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$A)*(if(offset('Form Responses 1'!$B$2:$B,0,1)="Break Start", -1, 1))))
```

[SAMPLE SHEET _ TAKE COPY](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17_hOIT1LEBbLWxFhNNJqOgU3bzpm_EjusP22NE4y9Vs/edit#gid=289291628)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to lock just the formatting of a sheet or range. If they are locked it will prevent everything from being changed. Best bet for this would be to create a copy of the sheet, format it how you would like, and protect it from everybody.

Then there are a couple of options:

- Go to the protected sheet, select all of the cells, and use format painter to copy the format to the working sheet.
- Write a script to copy the format of the protected sheet to the working sheet.

Another option would be to write a script to set the format of sheet. This can be setup to happen when the sheet is opened, edited or when you manually run the script.

Or

To keep some of your data in the same place, you can [freeze rows](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/54813?hl=en) and columns:

- Open a spreadsheet and select a cell in a row or column you want to freeze .
- Open the View menu.
- Hover over Freeze.
- Select one of the options to freeze up to ten rows, or five columns. You can also choose Up to current row (or Up to current column) to freeze the rows or columns before a cell you've highlighted.